# Do you know what they mean/meant by this?

Tags: grammar, sequence-of-tenses

I'm trying to ask the other person to clarify what he just said as he asked me about the size of a material.

His question:"What materials require the tools needed to move the 3 pallet sizes?"

He wanted to know which materials are 3-pallet large and thus would require the special equipment.

Please critique these sentences.

1. Do you know what they mean by 3 pallet sizes?
2. Do you know what they meant by 3 pallet sizes?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please give us more information. What is the material concerned?  What sizes does it come in? Is a pallet a measure of the size/weight/volume of  the material?

Comment: Either sentence could be correct, depending on the situation.

Comment: It's not quite the same as *He said his name was Smith*, where ***most*** people do in fact "backshift" from the (more logical?) alternative *his name **is** Smith* (it's ridiculously unlikely that he changed his name since saying what it was). That's because the "name" example focuses on ***what he actually said, in the past***, whereas in OP's example here, what matters is ***what it still means right now***. So in practice, I think many if not most native speakers would "**forward shift**" as per #1 above (it's as much a matter of ***preference*** as it is ***context / intended meaning***).

Comment: I think you can use either. The first one focusses on the meaning at this second in time. The second is saying "do you know what they meant when they wrote/said xyz?"

Comment: @RonaldSole I've edited my question to include his question. Please let me know if more information is needed. Thanks!

Comment: This question - grammar aside - would make sense to me if it read: **What equipment is required to move three pallet loads?** Or **What equipment is required to move a load equal to three pallets? Don't confuse **materials** (stone, sand, blocks) and **equipment** (cranes, diggers, forklifts, pallet jacks). Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct.

> 1. Do you know what they meant by 3 pallet sizes? = Do you know to what exactly they referred when they said "3 pallet sizes"? (emphasis on the particular use of the expression in that particular situation).

> 2. Do you know what they mean by 3 pallet sizes? = Do you know what is the definition of "3 pallet sizes" in ***their*** understanding? What do they generally understand by that? (emphasis on the understanding of a term used generally in such situations).

However, 2 is much more common. Emphasis on a singular use in a particular past situation is not frequent. It would be more plausible in such a situation:

> They said she was hard to please. I wonder what they ***meant*** by that.